# Cocos2d-x child sprite doesn't show up after removing and adding child

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i have node that holdes few sprites as children 
in some point i try to remove the last in the children vector and added as first 
the problem its never show up in the screen
do i need some refresh function after the remove/add action ?

```
pButtomReel = Node::create();
pButtomReel->addChild(sprite1);
pButtomReel->addChild(sprite2)
pButtomReel->addChild(sprite3)
pButtomReel->addChild(sprite4)

// every thing is renders right on the screen 

// now i try to remove and add sprites

Sprite *spriteLastToHandle = static_cast<Sprite*>(pButtomReel->getChildren().at(pButtomReel->getChildren().size()-1));               
Sprite *spriteFirstToHandle = static_cast<Sprite*>(pButtomReel->getChildren().at(0));

float YFirst = spriteFirstToHandle->getPositionY();
float XFirst = spriteFirstToHandle->getPositionX();

float YLast = spriteLastToHandle->getPositionY();
float XLast = spriteLastToHandle->getPositionX();

spriteFirstToHandle->setPosition(XLast,YLast);
int s1 = pButtomReel->getChildren().size();  //SHOWS RIGHT 4
pButtomReel->getChildren().erase(0);
int s2 = pButtomReel->getChildren().size(); //SHOWS RIGHT 3
pButtomReel->getChildren().insert(0,spriteLastToHandle);
 int s3 = pButtomReel->getChildren().size(); //SHOWS RIGHT 4 all looks fine
```

but the sprite i added in :

```
pButtomReel->getChildren().insert(0,spriteLastToHandle);
```

never show up 
why ?

Comment: I think you're not supposed to insert items directly to the children vector, instead use the addChild and (if available) insertChild methods.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is totally right. While adding directly to the array you skip all the logic behind the addChild method (just have a look at the source code). I don't know why your want to change the order of the child but you might manage your own array (or vector) but don't use insert or erase on getChildren.

Comment: well i wanted to do something like connected list ...
so why the methods are public ?

Comment: Have you tried to set zOrder to the addChild function. It may help cocos not to confuse when run insert function. I think it might help.